# Icinga2 and pnp4nagios

Tags: icinga

I am trying to install icinga2 and icingaweb with pnp4nagios. As directed in icinga2 [document](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/addons-plugins?highlight-search=PNP#addons-graphing-pnp) I have added following parameter on npcd.conf :

```
perfdata_spool_dir = /var/spool/icinga2/perfdata
```

I get the following error when accessing `localhost/pnp4nagios`:

```
Please check the documentation for information about the following error.
perfdata directory "/var/lib/pnp4nagios/" is empty. Please check your Nagios config. <a href="http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/faq/3">Read FAQ online</a>
file [line]:
application/models/data.php [109]:
back
```

I have enable the performance plugin perfdata.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind:

- npcd is not running (properly)
- npcd and icinga2 are running under different users? so npcd can't read/delete spool files
- Are there any files in /var/spool/icinga2/perfdata ? (Icinga feature enabled?)

For more help, logs might help.

Comment: Please disable npcd and check if Icinga is even writing files to that directory.

Comment: Let me check on it.